# Getting a string property from an ObservableCollection<CProject> object

Tags: c#, mvvm, observablecollection

In my C# application I'm calling a method which returns an array:

```
projectArray = client.getProjectList(username, password);
```

As I'd like to refactor the application to WPF using the MVVM pattern I should use an `ObservableCollection` for the project list.

My view model contains:

```
// Members
CProject[] projectArray;
ObservableCollection<CProject> projectList;

// Properties
public ObservableCollection<CProject> ProjectList {
  get { return projectList; }
  set {
    projectList = value;
    OnPropertyChanged("ProjectList");
  }
}
```

And the code for setting the property:

```
projectArray = client.getProjectList(username, password);
projectList = new ObservableCollection<CProject>(projectArray);
this.ProjectList = projectList;
```

Here comes the problem. My view contains a combobox which is bound to the view model's `ProjectList` property. The binding works fine. However the combobox displays values like `MyApp.SoapApi.CProject`. I'd like to display the names of the project which are accessible via `CProject.database.name`.

What is an appropriate and correct way doing this? I tried using `projectList = value.database.name` but this is a string which conflicts with the property type `CProject`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the DisplayMemberPath of your combobox to the path of the property you want to be shown in the combobox text:

```
<ComboBox DisplayMemberPath="database.name" />
```

also, your code can be simplified to just:

```
// Members
ObservableCollection<CProject> projectList;

// Properties
public ObservableCollection<CProject> ProjectList {
    get { return projectList; }
    set {
        projectList = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("ProjectList");
    }
}


this.ProjectList = new ObservableCollection<CProject>(client.getProjectList(username, password));
```

Answer (score 2):

Your combobox contains a Property called DisplayMemeberPath, set it to "database.name".
Use Views for output formatting, not View Models!

or create a template for the items in the combobox

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ...}">
<ComboBox.ItemsTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
<Label Content="{Binding database.name}"/>
</DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemsTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Both answers are working great for me. However I had to choose one :-)

Answer (score 1):

*First set the datacontext of your view to the ViewModel.*

*View :*

```
public YourWindowView()
        {

            this.DataContext = new YourWindowViewModel();
        }
```

*Then fill the Project list in ViewModel*
  *ViewModel:*

```
public class YourWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
            {
                    ObservableCollection<CProject> projectList;

        // Properties
        public ObservableCollection<CProject> ProjectList {
          get { return projectList; }
          set {
            projectList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ProjectList");
          }
        }

        public  YourWindowViewModel ()
            {
                // fill project list here
                 this.ProjectList = new ObservableCollection<CProject>(client.getProjectList(username, password));
             }
        }
```

*Bind to the View*

XAML

```
 <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ProjectList}"                
              IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
              DisplayMemberPath="database.name" />
```